# how to get the region after segmentaion?

Tags: matlab

[image: the boundary of segmentation]

just as the picture above shows ,I　have get the boundarys of one image after 
segmentaion . But I just get the logical boudarys and  I want to label each 
region that splited by segmentaion. function bwlabel doesn't work ,It can only
label connected region. so ,how can I label these two hundred regions ???

Comment: Does inverting then bwlabel work?

Answer (score 0):

If your original image is called *img* and your current bw segmented image is called *I*, I would suggest:

```
I = (I==0); % invert the image
cc = bwconncomp(I,8); % could use 4-connected neighborhood also
s = regionprops(cc,img,'all');
```

The last line will provide all the available properties from the original image for each segmented region (if you want it). You could use *bwlabel* as you mentioned, but I think *bwconncomp* may be faster/more efficient.

An alternative to *bwlabel* for labeling is:

```
L = labelmatrix(cc);
```

Then I like using *label2rgb* to view the segments:

```
RGB_label = label2rgb(L, @jet, 'k', 'shuffle');
imshow(RGB_label);
```

This will randomly color each segment according to the colormap provided (jet, in this case).